# Dropdown Menu appears fine in Chrome but not in Safari (covered by image)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

The Nav dropdown menu works fine in Chrome, but in Safari the rest of the menu is covered by the image.
Why is this happening only in Safari?  It displays just fine in Chrome.

Things I have attempted to no avail :

- meddled with Z-index
- tried using position:relative for the dropdown menu
- added on -webkit-transform

  ```js
   
  ;(function(){function t(){}function e(t){return null==t?t===l?d:y:I&&I in Object(t)?n(t):r(t)}function n(t){var e=$.call(t,I),n=t[I];try{t[I]=l;var r=true}catch(t){}var o=_.call(t);return r&&(e?t[I]=n:delete t[I]),o}function r(t){return _.call(t)}function o(t,e,n){function r(e){var n=d,r=g;return d=g=l,x=e,v=t.apply(r,n)}function o(t){return x=t,O=setTimeout(c,e),T?r(t):v}function i(t){var n=t-h,r=t-x,o=e-n;return w?k(o,j-r):o}function f(t){var n=t-h,r=t-x;return h===l||n>=e||n<0||w&&r>=j}function c(){
      var t=D();return f(t)?p(t):(O=setTimeout(c,i(t)),l)}function p(t){return O=l,S&&d?r(t):(d=g=l,v)}function s(){O!==l&&clearTimeout(O),x=0,d=h=g=O=l}function y(){return O===l?v:p(D())}function m(){var t=D(),n=f(t);if(d=arguments,g=this,h=t,n){if(O===l)return o(h);if(w)return O=setTimeout(c,e),r(h)}return O===l&&(O=setTimeout(c,e)),v}var d,g,j,v,O,h,x=0,T=false,w=false,S=true;if(typeof t!="function")throw new TypeError(b);return e=a(e)||0,u(n)&&(T=!!n.leading,w="maxWait"in n,j=w?M(a(n.maxWait)||0,e):j,S="trailing"in n?!!n.trailing:S),
      m.cancel=s,m.flush=y,m}function i(t,e,n){var r=true,i=true;if(typeof t!="function")throw new TypeError(b);return u(n)&&(r="leading"in n?!!n.leading:r,i="trailing"in n?!!n.trailing:i),o(t,e,{leading:r,maxWait:e,trailing:i})}function u(t){var e=typeof t;return null!=t&&("object"==e||"function"==e)}function f(t){return null!=t&&typeof t=="object"}function c(t){return typeof t=="symbol"||f(t)&&e(t)==m}function a(t){if(typeof t=="number")return t;if(c(t))return s;if(u(t)){var e=typeof t.valueOf=="function"?t.valueOf():t;
      t=u(e)?e+"":e}if(typeof t!="string")return 0===t?t:+t;t=t.replace(g,"");var n=v.test(t);return n||O.test(t)?h(t.slice(2),n?2:8):j.test(t)?s:+t}var l,p="4.17.5",b="Expected a function",s=NaN,y="[object Null]",m="[object Symbol]",d="[object Undefined]",g=/^\s+|\s+$/g,j=/^[-+]0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,v=/^0b[01]+$/i,O=/^0o[0-7]+$/i,h=parseInt,x=typeof global=="object"&&global&&global.Object===Object&&global,T=typeof self=="object"&&self&&self.Object===Object&&self,w=x||T||Function("return this")(),S=typeof exports=="object"&&exports&&!exports.nodeType&&exports,N=S&&typeof module=="object"&&module&&!module.nodeType&&module,E=Object.prototype,$=E.hasOwnProperty,_=E.toString,W=w.Symbol,I=W?W.toStringTag:l,M=Math.max,k=Math.min,D=function(){
      return w.Date.now()};t.debounce=o,t.throttle=i,t.isObject=u,t.isObjectLike=f,t.isSymbol=c,t.now=D,t.toNumber=a,t.VERSION=p,typeof define=="function"&&typeof define.amd=="object"&&define.amd?(w._=t, define(function(){return t})):N?((N.exports=t)._=t,S._=t):w._=t}).call(this);

  // This function will run a throttled script every 300 ms
  var checkHeader = _.throttle(() => { 
      console.log('checkHeader');

      // Detect scroll position
      let scrollPosition = Math.round(window.scrollY);

      // If we've scrolled 130px, add "sticky" class to the header
      if (scrollPosition > 130){
          document.querySelector('header').classList.add('sticky');
      }
      // If not, remove "sticky" class from header
      else {
          document.querySelector('header').classList.remove('sticky');
      }
  }, 300);

  // Run the checkHeader function every time you scroll
  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkHeader);
  ```

  ```css
  header{
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 120px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(9, 9, 22, 0.6), rgba(9, 9, 22, 1.0));
  }

   
  main{
      margin-top: 120px;
  }
   
  header.sticky {
      background-color: black;
      height: 90px;
  }

  header.sticky nav{
      top: 30px;
  }

  header.sticky #logo{
      font-size: 3em;
      padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  }

  header #logo{
      font-size: 5em;
      float: left;
  }

  .phi{
      color: rgb(141, 180, 105);
  }
  .hilo{
      color: white;
  }

  nav{
      float: right;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50px;
      left: 280px;
  }
  nav > a, .dropmenu{
      padding-left: 0.5em;
      padding-right: 0.5em;
  }
  nav a, .dropdown{
      color: rgb(240, 137, 52);
      font-size: 20px;
  }

  a{
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #ddd;
      min-width: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      border-radius: 21px 21px 21px 21px;
      z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: rgb(247, 185, 71); 
      border-radius: 21px 21px 21px 21px;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

  .dropmenu:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
  }

  .universe {
      background-image: url("../assets/img/universe.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25em;
      display: inline-block;
      z-index: -999;
  }
  blockquote{
      color: white;
      font-size: 4em;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2em auto;
  }
  .bgbutton, .bottominfo{
      background-color: white;
  }
  .button{
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: rgb(240, 137, 52);
      border: none;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      padding: 20px;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 50px 180px;
    }
  .button span{
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      transition: 0.5s ease;
  }
  .button span:after{
      content: '\00bb';
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: -20px;
      transition: 0.5s ease;
  }
  .button:hover span{
      padding-right: 25px;
  }
  .button:hover span:after{
      opacity: 1;
      right: 0;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="wrapper">
          <header>
              <a href="index.html">
                      <div id="logo">
                              <span class="phi">&#934</span><span class="hilo">hilo</span>
                          </div>
              </a>
              <nav>
                  <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropmenu">INTERIOR DESIGN</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="our-philosophy.html">OUR PHILOSOPHY</a>
                          <a href="our-innovation.html">OUR INNOVATION</a>
                          <a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="feng-shui.html">FENG SHUI</a>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropmenu">SERVICES</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="space-planning.html">SPACE PLANNING</a>
                          <a href="fengshui-consultation.html">FENG SHUI CONSULTATION</a>
                          <a href="design-renovation.html">DESIGN & CARPENTRY</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropmenu">OUR MASTERPIECE</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="residential.html">RESIDENTIAL</a>
                          <a href="retail.html">RETAIL</a>
                          <a href="corporate-office.html">CORPORATE & OFFICE</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                          <a class="dropmenu">ABOUT</a>
                          <div class="dropdown-content">
                              <a href="chief-designer.html">CHIEF DESIGNER</a>
                              <a href="master-pek.html">MASTER PEK</a>
                              <a href="subsidiaries.html">OUR SUBSIDIARIES</a>
                              <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
              </nav>
          </header>
          <main>
              <div  class="universe">
              <section>
                  <blockquote>Where Feng Shui Meets Design</blockquote>
              </section>
              </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the problem and came to a solution.
The problem was hidden at the header section.
After changing header - overflow: visible (from hidden), the dropdown menu in navbar is displaying properly now in Safari.
The reason Safari renders this so differently from Chrome is unfathomable.